# How to compare data as desired result

Tags: c#, .net

here is some function that i made

```
 public class Mycompare : IComparer<InventoryPick>
  {
      public int Compare(InventoryPick x, InventoryPick y)
      {
          if (MyConvert.ToUPPER(x.ItemNumber).EndsWith("-NK"))
          {
              return -1;
          }
          else if (MyConvert.ToUPPER(y.ItemNumber).EndsWith("-NK"))
          {
              return 1;
          }
          else //means equal
          {
              if (!MyConvert.IsNullOrEmpty(MyConvert.ToUPPER(x.KITNUMBER)) && !MyConvert.IsNullOrEmpty(y.KITNUMBER))
              { return 0; }
              else if (!MyConvert.IsNullOrEmpty(x.KITNUMBER))
              {
                  return -1;
              }
              else if (!MyConvert.IsNullOrEmpty(y.KITNUMBER))
              {
                  return 1;
              }
              return 0;
          }
      }
  }
```

here is currently data is coming

```
itemnumber                      kitnumber
BABY-KIT-my-NK                  NULL
x-KIT-my-NK                     NULL
item1                           BABY-KIT-my               
item2                           x-KIT-my                    
item3                           x-KIT-my
```

ok but i want it to be like this

```
itemnumber                      kitnumber
BABY-KIT-my-NK                  NULL
item1                           BABY-KIT-my   
x-KIT-my-NK                     NULL
item2                           x-KIT-my                    
item3                           x-KIT-my
```

HERE IS EXPLANATION
if "itemnumber" contains -NK THAN CONSIDER IT AS "KIT" AND THIS ITEM'S KITNUMBER IS ALWAYS BE NULL
IF "ItemNumber" is not contains -nk than its normal item.. & it may have kitnumber & it may have not..
so suppose if item is like BABY-KIT-my-NK so its kit & another item in list is normal item but its
"kitnumber" is like BABY-KIT-my than its this kit item...
basically i want it together..so i can pick it together so there is no issue with second kits..

i hope you understand..
the data what currently coming & what i wanted i showed above..

Comment: What if both `x` and `y` end with `-NK`?

Comment: @GuruStron
there will be always itemnumber who ends with -nk

Comment: It was a hint what is wrong with the converter) TBH the desired sorting rules are not clear - you want items sorted by kit number with items storing kit number in item number being closer to top?

Comment: @GuruStron yes  i have showen example for more understanding

Comment: `if (MyConvert.ToUPPER(x.ItemNumber).EndsWith("-NK"))` <-- There's at least five things wrong with this one line here, yikes.

Comment: @Dai what is wrong with it ?

Comment: 1. Don't reimplement basic functionality provided by your platform. 2. Converting a string to uppercase for comparison's sake is a waste because it allocates and copies the entire string, whereas `StringComparer` can perform an allocation-free case-insensitive string comparison for you. 3. You're dereferencing `x.ItemNumber` without checking if it's safe first (e.g. `x` could be `null`, and so could `x.ItemNumber` (it looks like a mutable `String` value). 4. In C# public methods are `PascalCase`  and not `LikeTHIS`. 5. Returning early with `-1` without ever comparing `x` to `y` is incorrect.

Comment: `else //means equal` <-- Your comment here is also incorrect. An `else` line does not imply or mean _anything_: the C# language does not have _algebraic_ language features or other nifty things like interval-types and compile-enforced exhaustiveness, that's why you can't make assumptions like that.

Comment: @Dai yes sir am understanding..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I doubt if your code can be compiled:

1. `Compare` instead of `CompareTo`
2. `ToUPPER`instead of `ToUpper`

When implementing `IComparer<T>` be sure that conditions below are met:

1. For any item `a`, `a.CompareTo(a) == 0` (i.e. `a` *equals to itself*).
2. If `a.CompareTo(b) == 0` and `b.CompareTo(c) == 0` then `a.CompareTo(c) == 0` (transitivity)
3. If `a.CompareTo(b) < 0` and `b.CompareTo(c) < 0` then `a.Compare(c) < 0` (transitivity)

In your case if `x == y == "bla-bla-bla-NK"` you return `-1` instead of `0` (your code insists on `x < x`)

I suggest something like this:

```
public class Mycompare : IComparer<InventoryPick> {
  public int CompareTo(InventoryPick x, InventoryPick y) {
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
      return 0;
    if (x is null)
      return -1;
    if (y is null)
      return 1;

    bool nkX = MyConvert.ToUPPER(x.ItemNumber).EndsWith("-NK");
    bool nkY = MyConvert.ToUPPER(y.ItemNumber).EndsWith("-NK");

    if (nkX && !nkY)
      return -1;
    if (!nkX && nkY)
      return 1;

    if (MyConvert.IsNullOrEmpty(x.KITNUMBER)) 
      return MyConvert.IsNullOrEmpty(y.KITNUMBER) ? 0 : -1;
    else if (MyConvert.IsNullOrEmpty(y.KITNUMBER))
      return 1;
      
    return 0;
  }
|
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have kits sorted, followed by the items with the corresponding kit number. The easiest way to solve this is to add a kitnumber for kits instead of null and then simply sort by kitnumber. You can delete the kit numbers from kits afterwards if you want.

This method is much simpler than writing a convoluted comparer (and it might even have better performance too).

Comment: _"The easiest way to solve this is to add a kitnumber for kits instead of null and then simply sort by kitnumber. You can delete the kit numbers from kits afterwards if you want."_ - This approach would be fine except it really doesn't work in a statically-typed language like C# where it's difficult to "attach" and remove data to extant objects - but would be perfect for JavaScript - or if you're comfortable with `ConditionalWeakTable`

Comment: @Dai well you can change strings or do other things, or you can leave the kitnumber be, if you are checking for the "nk" anyways. Generally the whole system looks like it was badly designed and needs some refactoring. At example checking for "nk" every time is costly, when you could simply use some flag in the object.

Comment: @MartinYakuza woah nice explanation sir.. Probably I will try that on Monday.. Thanks for information never thought of that.